# DOM XSS - is this actually exploitable?

Tags: javascript, security, dom, xss, secure-coding

CheckMarx found this and marked it as a vulnerability.  It doesn't seem to rely on user input, so I'm curious if this is actually exploitable.  This is activated by dragging a component.  If this is actually exploitable, suggestions on a fix?

This is what CheckMarx says:

> The application's this.componentsArray.forEach embeds untrusted data
> in the generated output with location. This untrusted data is embedded
> straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding,
> enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

```
public handleDragOverTouch(e: TouchEvent) {
        let x = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
        let y = e.changedTouches[0].clientY;

        let componentBeingDragged = this.componentsArray.find(child => child.instance.componentConfig.id === this.draggedId);

        if (componentBeingDragged !== null && componentBeingDragged !== undefined) {
            this.componentsArray.forEach(component => {

                let childLocation = component.location.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

                if (y > childLocation.top && y < childLocation.bottom && x > childLocation.left && x < childLocation.right) {
                    this.handleDrag(null, component.location, component.instance.componentConfig.id, x);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks completely normal to me. Unless the JS is already compromised, shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I'd assume `component.location` is the item the checker has stucked on, it's maybe considered as the location written in the address bar.

Comment: Ah, forgot to put what CheckMarx said the issue actually was, updated the question...

Comment: This is a false positive, I don't think it can be exploited.

Comment: What does `handleDrag` do? Because that's pretty crucial here. This is unlikely to be an XSS opportunity, but there is no way to tell right now.

Comment: None of the parameters to `handleDrag` seem to have string user inputs, so whatever it does, it's _very_ unlikely this is exploitable.